# How do Channels differ from Samples/Dimension?

Tags: nlp, conv-neural-network, dimensions

I am a confused about the definition of "channels" in various types of data.

In CNN, why Color Image is classified as 2D-data with 3 channels RGB (Deep Learning, Ian Goodfellow et al) but not 3D-data?

In a paper on LSTM with time-series data here (section 4.1), https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.03402.pdf
why did the author consider them different channels but not different samples?

In some papers on NLP, I often see the term channels too.

At the bottom line, what is "channel" intuitively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each pixel is a feature which has 3 channels, but there are 2D of these features.  in a sense you are right there are more than 2D features but spatially it is 2D. This is important because convolution operation takes is sliding filters over spatial dimensions.

Similarly, characters can be considered as features of sentences with 300D embeddings features. When applying convolutions, sentences are considered as 1D because the sliding window is moving along time-dimension only. The embeddings can be considered as channels in this case.

So, it depends on how you want to process and interpret a sequence of features. Usually, when time or space is involved, on each position in time and space the features are referred to as observable channels, in this case usually dimensionality of time-space is used for composing the observables into meaningful units.